# Silverlight player: Set video to fullscreen with button click (html/javascript)?

Tags: video, silverlight

Is there any way that I can set my video to fullscreen using an html button through javascript that communicates with the silverlight video player?

It's easily doable with Play, Pause, etc. But I can't seem to get it to work for Fullscreen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a security feature of Silverlight to stop Silverlight being used to scam people.

Full-screen can only be activated in response to a user input event "generated from within the Silverlight application".